# Itunes store transaction (In app purchase)

Tags: iphone, cordova, itunes-store, in-app-purchase

I'm currently developing a Phonegap mobile application.
I implemented In App purchase in my iPhone application and it works fine.
I retrieve my products informations from itunes, I got the receipt of payment from itunes store, my app is sending the receipt back to my servers, the receipt is verified server side using curl/apple api.

My issue is, on the server side when I log the purchase when receipt is OK using information of the receipt, so I know which product the user bought through the app, the datetime, the transaction id BUT I don't know how much the user paid for it. The same product is on different itunes store (US, FR, UK..), so the price could be 100E or 140$, but on the server side how can I retrieve the price and currency the user paid (to make statistics for example)?

Comment: Apple provides statistics of this in it's earnings report does it not?

Comment: It does but still, I need to get payment infos on the server side as soon as the payment has been done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think allow you to see the local purchase price.
Not really code related in that you select a purchase level and apple provides a chart in Itunesconnect to see what payment they take across a range of currencies .